# How do I enable JavaScript autoload function?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way I can enhance my script to autoload instead of using button. Also is there a way I can include fade-in style sort of in this script.

```
<script>
var content = [
  "Headline",
  "Headline 1",
  "Headline 2",
  "Headline 3",
];
var msgPtr = 0;
var stopAction = null;

function change() {
  var newMsg = content[msgPtr];
  document.getElementById('change').innerHTML = 'Breaking News: '+msgPtr+'<p>'+newMsg;
  msgPtr++;  msgPtr = (msgPtr % content.length);
}

function startFunction() { change();  stopAction = setInterval(change, 4000); }
function stopFunction() { clearInterval(stopAction); }

</script>
```

Comment: Did you give it a go? Show us :)

Comment: the most basic way would be to call `startFunction()` in a script tag just before `</body>` ... for fading, lookup CSS transitions

Answer (score 0):

With your current code you would just add a `startFunction();` to then end to get it to start automatically.

Getting it to fade in and out is a little more complicated. I would do something like this:

```
// encapsulate in an object this IIFE returns
var headlines = (function () {
    'use strict';
  var content = [
      "Headline",
      "Headline 1",
      "Headline 2",
      "Headline 3",
    ],
    running = false,
    displayForMs = 4000,
    msgPtr = 0,
    stopAction = null,
    display = document.getElementById('change');

  // just updates the message in the element
  function changeMsg() {
    var newMsg = content[msgPtr];
    display.innerHTML = 'Breaking News: '+msgPtr+'<p>'+newMsg;
    msgPtr += 1;
    msgPtr = msgPtr % content.length;
  }

  function hide () {
    display.classList.add('hide');
  }

  function show () {
    display.classList.remove('hide');
  }

  function update () {
    var opacity = window.getComputedStyle(display).opacity;

    // fade out has ended, change message and fade in
    if (opacity === '0') {
      changeMsg();
      show();
    // fade in has ended, start waiting to trigger update
    } else if (opacity === '1') {
        stopAction = setTimeout(hide, displayForMs);
    }
  }

  display.addEventListener('transitionend', update, false);

  function startFunction() {
    running = true;
        // hiding causes an update()
    // update does not trigger if the element
    // is already invisible, show() to ensure
    // it has an opacity over 0
        show();
    // we have to wait for a repaint before calling hide
    // if we don't the hide class will be removed and readded
    // in the same frame too fast for the opacity to change
    // and the update will never fire
    requestAnimationFrame(function () {
      hide();
    });
  }

  function stopFunction() {
    running = false;
    clearTimeout(stopAction);
    // remove hide class just to continue to display
    // message and prevent another call to update
    // in case it was mid-fade out
    display.classList.remove('hide');
  }

  return {
    start: startFunction,
    stop: stopFunction,
    get running () {
        return running;
    }
  };
}());

var toggle = document.getElementById('headline-toggle');
toggle.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (headlines.running) {
    headlines.stop();
    toggle.textContent = "Resume";
  } else {
    headlines.start();
    toggle.textContent = "Stop";
  }
}, false);

headlines.start();
```

This requires adding the `.change` class to the `#change` element and adding this CSS:

```
.change.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

The code uses CSS transitions to hide and show the element by adding and removing the `hide` class. The [`transitionend` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) detects when the element has an opacity of `'0'`and then calls `update` which changes the message via `changeMsg` and then calls `show`. `show` shows the element by removing the `'hide'` class. `update` will get called again when the element has an opacity of `'1'`, this fires the timeout to trigger the next fade out.

[Functioning example here](https://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/mxyvLzxd/)

**update 2016-08-29** I've change the way the fade code works a little. The timer is now triggered once the fade in is complete allowing the message to be displayed for the full `displayForMs` count instead of being effected by the length of the transition. I also changed start a bit; it no longer requires that the element be visible when it is called. I also added a `.running` property to `headlines` so you can query whether it is currently running or not. The jsFiddle uses this to use a single toggle button instead of separate Start and Stop buttons.

**update 2016-09-02**
I updated the example a little more, I added [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) and turned `.running` into a getter instead of a function. That way you can do `if (headlines.running)` instead of `if (headlines.running())`.

Also, I've created a [micro-library based on the code](https://github.com/uselesscode/headline-fader) I wrote for this answer. If you use bower you can install it with `bower install headline-fader`.

Using it, to do something similar to what you were doing in your code, plus auto-starting it, you would do this:

```
var headlineElement = document.getElementById('change'),
  myHeadlines = headlineFader(headlineElement, {
    headlines: [
      'Headline',
      'Headline 1',
      'Headline 2',
      'Headline 3',
    ],
    wait: 4000, // this is optional, the library defaults to 7000
  });

myHeadlines.start();
```